# How to open the User certificates view from the device settings programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, certificate, settings, pixel

I really need to open, from my app, the User certificates view using an Intent.

This is the view:

[image]

This view, in most devices, can be found under Settings > Security and privacy > Other security settings > User certificates

So far, I manage to do it and tested it on a Samsung device using:

`startActivity(Intent("com.android.settings.USER_CREDENTIALS"))`

However, this does not work on a Pixel 7 Pro device, as there is "no activity" which could handle the Intent.

Is there any generic solution for this view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

will open the `Security & Privacy settings` page on your device. From there, you can tap on the `"Other security settings"` option to view the `User certificates view`.